# Scanner not placing external file in linked list

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have searched for this question and I am still at a loss after trying alot.  I am completely new to Java so please excuse the ignorance.  I am trying to read in a file from the scanner.  The file contains SmartPhone attributes and I would like to assign them directly to the smartphone class variables and then create my phone and add it to the list.  However, the phones are not getting added and I have made sure that the text file is in the format that the scanner and class attributes are expecting.  Can anyone spot my mistake?

```
package model;
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 


public class menu {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int inputOption;
        SmartPhone newPhone;
        LinkedList<SmartPhone> phoneList;
        FileToLinkedList smartphoneList;

        smartphoneList = new FileToLinkedList();
        phoneList = smartphoneList.createDatabase();
        System.out.println(phoneList);


        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        //userInput.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        int smartphoneLabel = 0;
        String model = "";
        String manufacturer = "";
        int year = 0;
        double price = 0.0;
        String color = "";


        System.out.println("==============================");
        System.out.println("   SmartPhone Database Menu   ");
        System.out.println("==============================");
        System.out.println("Options:                      ");
        System.out.println("  1.  Display all smartphones ");
        System.out.println("  2.  Add a smartphone        ");
        System.out.println("  3.  Delete a smartphone     ");
        System.out.println("  4.  Search for a smartphone ");
        System.out.println("  5.  Quit                    ");
        System.out.println("==============================");

        inputOption = KeyIn.inInt("Please select an option from the menu: ");

        switch(inputOption){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("You've selected to display the entire smartphone database.");



                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("You have chosen to add a smartphone to the database. ");
                System.out.println("Smartphone Label: ");
                smartphoneLabel = userInput.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Model: ");
                model = userInput.next();
                System.out.println("Manufacturer: ");
                manufacturer = userInput.next();
                System.out.println("Year: ");
                year = userInput.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Price: ");
                price = userInput.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Color: ");
                color = userInput.next();

                newPhone = new SmartPhone(smartphoneLabel, model, manufacturer, year, price, color);
                phoneList.add(newPhone);                



                System.out.println("Here is your new database of smartphones. ");
                //phoneList.displayDatabase();

                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("You have chosen to delete a smartphone from the database. ");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("You have chosen to search for a particular model." );
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid selection.");
                break;              
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
package model;

import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 

public class FileToLinkedList extends LinkedList {
    LinkedList<SmartPhone> myPhoneList;

    public FileToLinkedList(){
        myPhoneList = new LinkedList<SmartPhone>();
    }

    public LinkedList<SmartPhone> createDatabase(){

        try{
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner("SmartPhone_Database.txt");
        while(scanner.hasNext()) {

            SmartPhone newPhone = new SmartPhone();

            newPhone.setLabel(scanner.nextInt());
            newPhone.setModel(scanner.nextLine());
            newPhone.setManufacturer(scanner.nextLine());
            newPhone.setYear(scanner.nextInt());
            newPhone.setPrice(scanner.nextDouble());
            newPhone.setColor(scanner.nextLine());
            //phoneList.add(newPhone);
            ((LinkedList<SmartPhone>)myPhoneList).add(newPhone);
        }    
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e){}
        return myPhoneList;
    }
}
```

---

***I have listed two ways that have been suggested, one commented out--but still nothing..**

```
package model;
import java.lang.*;

public class SmartPhone {
    private int smartphoneLabel;
    private String model;
    private String manufacturer;
    private int year;
    private double price;
    private String color;

    //constructor
    public SmartPhone(){
        smartphoneLabel = 0;
        model = "";
        manufacturer = "";
        year = 0;
        price = 0.0;
        color = "";
    }

    public SmartPhone(int myLabel, String myModel, String myManufacturer, int myYear, double myPrice, String myColor)
    {
            smartphoneLabel = myLabel;
            model = myModel;
            manufacturer = myManufacturer;
            year = myYear;
            price = myPrice;
            color = myColor;
    }

    public int getLabel(){
        return smartphoneLabel;
    }

    public String getModel(){
        return model;
    }

    public String getManufacturer(){
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public int getYear(){
        return year;
    }

    public double getPrice(){
        return price;
    }

    public String getColor(){
        return color;
    }

    public void setLabel(int label){
        smartphoneLabel = label;
    }

    public void setModel(String model){
        model = model;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer){
        manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public void setYear(int year){
        year = year;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price){
        price = price;
    }

    public void setColor(String color){
        color = color;
    }



    public void display(){
        System.out.println("Label: " + getLabel() + "\n");
        System.out.println("Model: " + getModel() + "\n");
        System.out.println("Manufacturer: " + getManufacturer() + "\n");
        System.out.println("Year: " + getYear() + "\n");
        System.out.println("Price: " + getPrice() + "\n");
        System.out.println("Color: " + getColor() + "\n");

    }
}
```

And this is my text file:

```
1234    NC2000  Nokia   2009    100.00  Silver
3874    CT4500  iPhone  2012    450.00  White
59780   F5600   Android 2012    475.00  Black
5983    T95000  Android 2011    500.00  Silver
23300   GH3000  Samsung 2010    275.00 Black
47000   TT2700  Samsung 2009    100.00 Silver
```

Comment: Which phoneList is supposed to be holding the SmartPhones?  You have one in both menu and FileToLinkedList.

Comment: good point I went ahead and changed it to be a little more clear. The FileToLinkedList is supposed to read the file and throw it in myPhoneList (local linked list) and then since it returns a list, I copy what it returns into my local list in main which is where the database of phones should live. I think..I'm not sure my design choices are the smartest...could it be because I am setting a linkedlist = to some other linkedlist and I need to overload the assignment operator for linked lists somehow?  would that be in FileToLinkedList?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your return statement for createDatabase().  You only return a LinkedList when there is an InputMismatchException, when you want to return myPhoneList every single time the method is called.  That should fix things right up for you.